# How to repeat this small program until EOF

Tags: java

The last piece that I want to add to this program is so that it will repeat after printing the results until EOF is pressed. Here is my code

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner stdin = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer > 2. Press EOF to quit: ");
    int num = stdin.nextInt();       
    while(stdin.hasNextInt)
    {
        if(num < 3)
        {
            System.out.println("Your input " + num + " is not a positive integer > 2");
        }
        else
        {
            int prime = 0;int pnum = 0;int dnum = 0;int anum = 0;
            for(int i = 2;i <= num;i++)
            {
                if(NumberClassifier.isPrime(i)==true)
                {
                    prime++;
                }
                if(NumberClassifier.classify(i)==1)
                {
                    pnum++;
                }
                else if(NumberClassifier.classify(i)==2)
                {
                    dnum++;
                }
                else if(NumberClassifier.classify(i)==3)
                {
                    anum++;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("In the range of 2 - " + num + " there are:");
            System.out.println(prime + " prime numbers");
            System.out.println(pnum + " perfect numbers");
            System.out.println(anum + " abundant numbers");
            System.out.println(dnum + " deficient numbers");
            System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer > 2. Press EOF to quit: ");
        }
    }
    //System.out.println("Please enter a positive integer > 2. Press EOF to quit: "); ( dont know where this should be)

}
```

This program takes an integer and runs the range of 2 - the integer through 2 methods which count the prime, abundant, deficient and perfect numbers in the range. I just want to get the input printed and then print the instructions again and run until EOF is pressed. I tried using a while loop to only continue the program while the scanner has an integer but that didnt seem to work at all.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "I tried using a while loop to only continue the program while the scanner has an integer but that didnt seem to work at all." Please show us the code.

Comment: added it but now its gonna confuse people as I dont believe it is close to working at all

Answer (score 0):

- `java.util.Scanner.hasNextInt` is a method, so you have to *call it* in order to use it.
- You have to read the value *inside the loop*.

Change

```
int num = stdin.nextInt();       
while(stdin.hasNextInt)
{
```

to

```
while(stdin.hasNextInt())
{
    int num = stdin.nextInt();
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you